# Tracking downloads and views separately (pdfs) with google analytics?

Tags: php, google-analytics, tracking, universal-analytics

So I have links on a site set up so if you click on the pdf version it will take you to view the pdf in browser. the other document types (powerpoint, excel, etc) are automatically downloaded with the one click so those are definitely and accurately tracked as downloads.

Is there a way to make it so that downloads of pdfs and views of pdfs are counted separately?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by separating clicks and views? I presume that you are already tracking pdf clicks already if you are already tracking all the other file types successfully? The methodology is the same. So are you talking about sending a page view as well?

Comment: From GAs point of view there is no difference between a pdf download and a pdf view, so if you want one number for people who watch the pdf in the browser and one for people who save it to the disk (which is how I read your question) then no, this will not work.

Comment: yea it looks like the most I can do is track a pdf click as a pageview, but it doesn't seem like there's anyway to track like a Right Click>Save As type of thing

Comment: No, as @EikePierstorff mentioned, it is not possible to track PDF views. Closest you will get is to fire a virtual page view that would mimic a view of the file as if it were another page on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`<a href="link/to/file.pdf" onclick="ga('send','event','pdf','click','file.pdf')">`

[Link Event Tracking - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Comment: This will not differentiate between "downloads of pdfs and views of pdfs" as asked by the OP (personally I don't think that's even possible).